# Does this video depict wrongly the phrase "to rinse the dishes"

Tags: meaning

> rinse something: to remove the soap from something with clean water
>   after washing it [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rinse_1?q=rinse)

This is to rinse the dishes [source](http://www.needinstructions.com/home_improvement_garden/instruction/440_how_to_wash_dishes_properly/)[image]

However, in this video, nreally at the end of the video, they depicted "*to rinse the dishes*" like "*to dry the dishes*" http://youtu.be/IHqcDg-1iAA

*Does the above video depict wrongly the phrase  "**to rinse the dishes**"*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the video is depicting "wiping" as "rinsing".

Comment: I watched it...inaccurate...I suppose their excuse would be that showing "rinse" was harder than "wipe."  Your picture shows rinse.

Comment: @Rathony - that's a legitimate doubt a non-native may have watching the video.

Comment: @Josh61 I am not sure about legitimacy, but I think it should be either closed or asked in ELL. "Rinse" and "wipe" are too distinct to be confused.

Comment: Just wanna ask if that video is saying correctly? cos it was made by a natve English speaker & that caused confusing

Comment: @Rathony - I can be moved to ELL, but the question is just fine.

Comment: @Josh61 The way he writes English makes me convinced you are right about moving it to ELL.

Comment: @Rathony You know it's showing wiping and not rinsing, but Tom doesn't...that's why he's asking.  What you're really saying is "I'm voting to close this because I already know the answer."  That said, this is better for ELL.

Comment: @michael_timofeev What you are doing now is speculating. I just stated the fact as I have one of five votes required to close this question. If nobody else agrees, I am fine.

Comment: @Rathony I'm not speculating.  Your language says that.   Think about it.  Just because rinse and wipe are clear for you doesn't mean it's clear for Tom.  He says he is confused because he doesn't think a native speaker would make this kind of mistake.

Comment: @michael_timofeev You and Tom are speculating that a native speaker would not make this kind of mistake. Actually how do you know it was made by a native speaker? Just because there was a native pronunciation? Any non-native speakers can make it by copying the pronunciations of dictionaries or You-tubes. Then???

Comment: @michael_timofeev Did you watch the video? Do you think it was made to teach high-level English to a native children? Do you use "make for" in place of "raise"?

Comment: @michael_timofeev Then, you are now agreeing that Tom is speculating. Details of the video don't matter at all. The most important thing is the OP was speculating and the question started from the speculation.

Comment: @michael_timofeev If someone asks, "a native speaker told me it is rinsing rather than wiping" showing a picture of "wiping", would you consider it "on-topic"? Read it after you wake up tomorrow. I really had difficulties in undertstanding your words myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Rinse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rinse)*** means:

> - remove (soap, for example) by washing lightly in water.

just like in the image you have posted.

- actually in the video it looks like they are ***[wiping](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wipe)*** the dishes, which is something you'd normally do after rinsing.

> - to subject to light rubbing or friction, as with a cloth or paper, in order to clean or dry.

(The Free Dictionary)